# Stop a post request function from executing based on a promise value?

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

When I process a POST request in express, I need to fetch some data on a mongoDB cluster, and based on the response I have to respond with the request.

```js
app.post('/api/persons', (request, response) => {
  const body = request.body;

  if (!body.name || !body.number) {
    return response.status(400).json({
      error: 'Name or Number missing',
    });
  }

  const newName = body.name;
  // if (phoneBook.some((person) => person.name === newName)) {
  //   return response.status(409).send({ error: 'Name should be unique' });
  // }
  Person.find({ name: newName }).then((num) => {
    if (num.length !== 0) {
      return response.status(409).json({
        error: 'Name must be unique',
      });
    }
  });

  const record = new Person({
    name: body.name,
    number: body.number,
  });

  record.save().then((savedRecord) => {
    response.json(savedRecord);
  });
});
```

Person is a mongoDB model

The `Person.find` checks the value and responds with a bool value. I'm currently facing two problems

1. After fetching value from the `.find` call, the function should end as I respond with return value but it still goes on and saves the value with `record.save()` below.
2. Even if the value does not exist, it still shows a `Name must be unique` error.
   // Fixed it by replacing `.exist()` to `.find()`

Is there a way to fix this without adding the `record.save()` inside the find promise? I want the `.find` call to exist in it's own function, how would I go about doing this ?

Thanks

Comment: The return is only executed if `num.length !== 0`, is this the case / expected outcome?

Comment: @axtck Yeah that part works fine. But the function execution does not stop here, what I what is to stop the execution and return with 409 response but it still goes on and executes till the last time even after returning the 409 response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a separate `findFunction` that will call `Person.find` and take `newName`, `foundCallback` and `notFoundCallback` as arguments. Please check the following code.

```
const findFunction = (newName, foundCallback, notFoundCallback) => {
    Person.find({ name: newName }).then((num) => {
        if (num.length !== 0) {
            foundCallback();
        } else {
            notFoundCallback();
        }
    });
}

app.post('/api/persons', (request, response) => {
    const body = request.body;

    if (!body.name || !body.number) {
        return response.status(400).json({
            error: 'Name or Number missing',
        });
    }

    const newName = body.name;

    findFunction(
        newName,
        () => response.status(409).json({ error: 'Name must be unique' }),
        () => {
            const record = new Person({
                name: body.name,
                number: body.number,
            });

            record.save().then((savedRecord) => {
                response.json(savedRecord);
            });
        }
    );
});
```

If you prefer a promise based solution then:

```
const ensurePersonIsUnique = (newName) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Person.find({ name: newName }).then((num) => {
            if (num.length !== 0) {
                reject();
            } else {
                resolve();
            }
        });
    });
}

app.post('/api/persons', (request, response) => {
    const body = request.body;

    if (!body.name || !body.number) {
        return response.status(400).json({
            error: 'Name or Number missing',
        });
    }

    const newName = body.name;

    ensurePersonIsUnique(newName).then(() => {
        const record = new Person({
            name: body.name,
            number: body.number,
        });

        record.save().then((savedRecord) => {
            response.json(savedRecord);
        });
    }).catch(() => {
        response.status(409).json({ error: 'Name must be unique' })
    });
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I figured out the promise solution too. Thanks